# Magnetic flux outside a solenoid perpendicular to the direction of axis of solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, emc, solenoid, magnetics, emf

I know that using straight forward Biot-Svart law it is possible to calculate field inside a solenoid or at a point on an axis away from the circular coil.
Now is it possible to calculate the Flux outside a solenoid (OFF AXIS) in direction perpendicular to the direction of axis of the solenoid ? I know it is much weaker outside but still can we deduce it mathematically ?

Comment: Sure.  One method would be to solve for the field of a single turn everywhere in space.  (I think that was done in my freshman physics class.) And then add up the fields for a number of turns (all at different places.)

Comment: This is the linear motor principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Biot-Savart law allows you to calculate the flux density at any point from any shaped coil you choose to describe: -

[image]

[image]

Pictures taken from [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/biosav.html#c2)

So, if you can mathematically derive a relationship between point p (at radius r) and the shape of the coil, you are in business. The trick, of course, is integrating all the infinitesimally short lengths of wire carrying the current for one turn then, repeating this for the length of the solenoid. It can get really tricky of course.